# MVC4 jquery to deselect Html.CheckboxListFor

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, checkboxlist

I'm using jquery to show and hide sections of a search page. I have a Html.Textbox and Html.CheckboxListFor that I show and hide base on form input (when the form is submitted it will show/hide the textbox if there is nothing entered in the textbox and same goes for the checkbox section, if not checkboxes are selected when the form is submitted the checkbox section is hidden when the page redisplays. I'm also using a jquery .click function to show/hide these search options as needed.

The code for the click functions:

```
    $('b.Text').click(function () {
        $('div.TSearch').slideDown(200);
        $('div.KSearch').slideUp(200);
    });


    $('b.Keyword').click(function () {
        $('div.KSearch').slideDown(200);
        $('div.TSearch').slideUp(200);
        $('#SearchString').val('');
    });


    $('b.Both').click(function () {
        $('div.KSearch').slideDown(200);
        $('div.TSearch').slideDown(200);
    });

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div>
        <!-- For styling the check boxes & text for the keywords section -->
        <style type="text/css">
            label {
                display: inline-block;
                padding: 5px;
                font-size:small;
            }
            input[type="submit"] {
                margin-left: 0px;
            }
        </style>
        @{ var htmlListInfo = new HtmlListInfo(HtmlTag.table, 5, null,
                                  TextLayout.Default, TemplateIsUsed.No);
        }

        @Html.CheckBoxListFor(model => model.KeywordIDs,
                              model => model.Keywords,
                              model => model.KeywordId,
                              model => model.Name,
                              model => model.SelectedKeywords,
                              htmlListInfo
        )

    </div>

}
```

**EDIT**

ViewModel:

```
public class SearchCasefileViewModel
{
    public Casefile Casefile;
    public Keyword Keyword;

    public IEnumerable<Casefile> Casefiles { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Keyword> Keywords { get; set; }

    public IList<Keyword> SelectedKeywords { get; set; }
    public List<string> KeywordIDs { get; set; }

}
```

As you can see when you click on the Keyword it hides the text box and clears the text box. I've tried to implement the same for the checkboxes by using Model.SelectedKeywords.Clear() but that doesn't update the page view so the check boxes are still checked. Is there a similar call that I can use to clear the check boxes?

Comment: Please update your question with your view model class and razor code/HTML for generating the check boxes; it is difficult to provide an accurate answer without this information.  Also when you say you tried `Model.SelectedKeywords.Clear()`, do you do this when the form is submitted?  Clearing the collection may certainly have no affect on the check boxes but again it depends on your view model and how it is being rendered.

Comment: I can use the SelectedKeywords.Clear() and it will only work when the form is submitted but I need to clear the checkmarks when the checkbox section is hidden.

Comment: Are you using this? http://mvccbl.com/Examples

Comment: Yes I am using the  mvccbl.com/Examples as a guide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a client side solution to uncheck all the boxes you can use this when the checkbox section is hidden:

```
// this selector is a bit general and you should use an id or class tagged on the
// checkbox section to make it more specific
$('form:checkbox').prop('checked', false);
```

Comment: Because this is automatically generated by the Html helper CheckBoxListFor, the id is unique to each checkbox and I'm not quite sure how I would attach a classId to it.

Comment: I took your example and after looking at the html that was generated I changed from 'form:checkbox' to 'input:checkbox' and that worked perfectly.